# Getting duplicates even with Select Distinct

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a query in which I should get the company information; however, I should be getting only 2 record and I'm getting 6 records.
Below is my query.

```
SELECT  distinct    a.FOLIO                     
                    ,a.MAIN_ADDRESS1
                    ,a.MAIN_ADDRESS2
                    ,b.COMPANY_NAME
                    ,b.FIRST_NAME
                    ,b.LAST_NAME
                    ,a.OPEN
                    ,a.CLOSE
                    ,c.CC
                    ,c.CNAME                

FROM vw_CODE_CASE AS a
INNER JOIN vw_CODE_CASE_VIOLATOR_CONTACTS AS b ON b.CMCODECASEID=a.CMCODECASEID 
INNER JOIN vw_CODE_CASE_WORK_FLOW AS c ON c.CMCODECASEID=a.CMCODECASEID
```

Is it possible that is because of the amount of inner joins? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Surely one or more columns would be displaying data differently than the other. Post sample data and expected output. Also, what is your current output?

Comment: DISTINCT doesn't apply to one Field, it applies to the whole row (the combination of All the fields).  Your best bet is to isolate a representative sample of data, showing what you have in the database, then including the results you desire from that example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without sample data it would be difficult to identify that due to which column the distinct data are not coming from your query.

But you can do one thing to identify the cause, You can try remove one by one column and check the data from your query. At the point when you get your expected data, the last removed column will be the cause behind your problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a comment. Not an Answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment P Shah. I did that and found out which column was generating the duplicates and from which table. Now I know for future reference an easy way to identify when I run into this problem againi